# Dask from_delayed() causing high memory usage

Tags: python, pandas, dask, dask-distributed

I'm following the instructions from (https://docs.dask.org/en/stable/delayed-collections.html) to create a custom data loader for a Dask DataFrame, which is basically this:

```py
import dask.dataframe as dd
from dask.delayed import delayed
dfs = [delayed(load)(fn) for fn in filenames]
df = dd.from_delayed(dfs, meta=types)
```

I have 10k filenames and I'm specifying the `meta` attribute (type are correct). The issue is that this is eating a lot of memory and making workers to be paused. If I do the same but with dask arrays it works fine, but if I do that by returning Pandas DataFrames from the `load()` function, it gets this high memory usage to the point of exhausting the system memory. Isn't this approach supposed to scale well ? Are there other ways to load DataFrames (by parts) in Dask ?

I'm using `dask==2023.5.0`.

Answer (score 0):

Answer my own question: the issue seems to be caused by a parameter of the `load()` function, if that parameter is too large to serialize it starts to accumulate memory.

Comment: If its a single large parameter for all calls, maybe you can use client.scatter or have it as its own delayed object before passing to load().

Comment: Thanks @mdurant, the solution was indeed to use its own delayed object before passing to load(). You can add an answer with it and I can accept as the correct answer as well, up to you.

Comment: Feel free to edit your answer with your best working solution and then you can accept that :)